# How to pass a column name as an argument of a function which uses dplyr, without passing it as a string?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here: https://rpubs.com/hadley/dplyr-programming they write the following.

```
my_summarise <- function(df, group_by) {
  group_by <- enquo(group_by)
  print(group_by)

  df %>%
    group_by(!!group_by) %>%
    summarise(a = mean(a))
}

my_summarise(df, g1)
#> ~g1
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      g1     a
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1   4.5
#> 2     2   2.0
```

So I try to copy it, using my idea of a function and my data.

```
library(MASS)
not.fun <- function(data, column) {
  column <- enquo(column)
  data %>% slice(1:10) %>% select(!!column)
}

not.fun(MASS::Cars93, Length)
Error in select(., !!column) : unused argument (!!column)
```

But, guess what, it doesn't work.
How to make it work, without using strings?
I would be interested in a result possibly done in base R if it'd take as many lines of code to write as a result in some specific package.

Comment: Not able to replicate the error.  Please check your `dplyr` version

Comment: Can you also try wtih `not.fun <- function(data, column) { data %>% slice(1:10) %>% select({{column}})}` as these are working for me

Comment: Here's perhaps a more up-to-date guide on using quasiquotation: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html

Answer (score 2):

The `MASS` package has it's own `select()` function. If you load MASS after you load `dplyr`, you mask the `dplyr` version of the function. You could be expliclt about which select function you want:

```
library(MASS)
not.fun <- function(data, column) {
  column <- enquo(column)
  data %>% slice(1:10) %>% dplyr::select(!!column)
}

not.fun(MASS::Cars93, Length)
```

Comment: Wow... It seems that it indeed was the problem. Thank you. The strange thing is that it appeared even without my importing `MASS`. And `select` outside of the function worked as `select` from `dplyr`.

Comment: ...or at least that's how I remember it today :p

Answer (score 1):

It is likely to be an issue of function masking as @MrFlick described in his post.   If that issue is resolved, instead of the `enquo/!!` the curly-curly operator can be used `{{..}}` as well

```
not.fun <- function(data, column) { 
                    data %>%
                         slice(1:10) %>%
                         dplyr::select({{column}})
   }


not.fun(MASS::Cars93, Length)
#   Length
#1     177
#2     195
#3     180
#4     193
#5     186
#6     189
#7     200
#8     216
#9     198
#10    206
```

Comment: How is that any different than using `enquo` and `!!`? Won't that produce the exact same results?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, for many arguments, the enquo !! won't have to be repeated.  Otherwise, one have to call enquo separately. for each argument and then do the `!!`

Comment: But that doesn't seem at all to address the "unused argument" problem the OP explicitly is posting about.

Comment: @MrFlick Your post already addressed that issue which I doon't want to repeat.  If that solves the issue, this is an alternative

Comment: My point is that if the OP wanted. to use it for future, this is an alternative approach when that namespace issue got resolved